# ANSI C - Get random words of each array

Tags: arrays, c, random, ansi-c

I'm having some issues on my code to generate 6 random human characters and 6 random numbers, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char name[5] = {'Daniel','Bill','Ben','Steve','Drew'};
char animals[5] = {'Dog','Cat','Mouse','Chicken','Bird'};
int age[5] = {25,17,18,50,10};
char city[5] = {'Palo Alto','Escondido','Chicago','Mumbai','Zapopan'};

int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
int a = rand(),b = rand(),c = rand(),d = rand(),e = rand(),f = rand();
printf("Name: %c\nAnimal: %c\nAge: %d\nCity: %c",name[a],animals[a],age[a],city[a]);
printf("Name: %c\nAnimal: %c\nAge: %d\nCity: %c",name[b],animals[b],age[b],city[b]);
printf("Name: %c\nAnimal: %c\nAge: %d\nCity: %c",name[c],animals[c],age[c],city[c]);
printf("Name: %c\nAnimal: %c\nAge: %d\nCity: %c",name[d],animals[d],age[d],city[d]);
printf("Name: %c\nAnimal: %c\nAge: %d\nCity: %c",name[e],animals[e],age[e],city[e]);
printf("Name: %c\nAnimal: %c\nAge: %d\nCity: %c",name[f],animals[f],age[f],city[f]);
return 0;
}
```

It doesn't seem to work S: I'm a begginer, can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: `rand()` returns a value from 0 to `RAND_MAX`. Based on that, you'll need to make sure they're valid indices.

Comment: The suggestions below for using `rand() % 5` are probably sufficiently accurate for this exercise, but the selections are not quite equi-probable.  Suppose RAND_MAX is 32767.  Then there are 6554 possible ways to get each of 0, 1, 2, but only 6553 possible ways to get each of 3, 4.  In some applications, that might matter; this is unlikely to be one of them.

Comment: As things are, you won't get much variety; if the name is Daniel, the city is always Palo Alto, etc.  You also make no provision for ensuring that the sets of values are different; you could easily end up with two sets of data the same, and three isn't too unlikely either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the random value is less than the number of elements in the array.

Something like,

```
int a = rand() % 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use `%s`, not `%c`; s prints a string, c a character.
- `rand() % 5` or you'll be out-of-bounds nearly all of the time.
- Use a separate index for each row, unless you want to only have the nth in each array for any given n.

Answer (score 1):

as you have array of 5 elements so you need random number from 0-4 so you should use:

`int number = rand() % 5; // range 0-4`

Answer (score 0):

`rand()%5`, since you only want index between 0 and 4

And since your `printf` function is always the same and the only thing that changes is the index that you are using, you can put it in a loop and use only one variable instead of 6.